# How do I restart an async.waterfall if error thrown?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am building a Twitter bot game in node.js. I have a script that has a synchronous function (`streamOn` which opens Twitter stream) and then an `async.waterfall` that has an HTTP GET request function (`getImage`). `getImage` sometimes returns a 301 response when the script is triggered. the `streamOn` continues to stay open but the player doesn't know about the error, just that no image is returned.

How do I get the `async.waterfall` to "retry" from the beginning of its steps if it throws an error so the player still gets an image?

Here is the `async.waterfall`:

```
streamOn(function(tweet) {
  async.waterfall([
    getName,
    searchImage,
    getImage,
    postTweet.bind(null, tweet)
  ],
  function(error, result) {
    if (error) {
      console.error(error);
      return;
    }
    console.log(result);

  });
}
```

and here is a simplified version of the `getImage` function:

```
function getImage() {

    var http=require('http'), imageBuffer;

    http.get(
      'http://www.kame.net/img/kame-anime-small.gif',
      function(res) {
        var body=new Buffer(0);

        if (res.statusCode!==200) {
          return console.error('HTTP '+res.statusCode);
        }

        res.on('data', function(chunk) {
          body=Buffer.concat([body, chunk]);
        });

        res.on('end', function() {
          imageBuffer=body;
        });

        res.on('error', function(err) {
          console.error(err);
        });
      }
    );
}
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, 301 isn't an error. It's telling you that your URL needs to be updated. Have you looked into why you're getting a redirect response?

Comment: @mdickin Yes, thanks for the clarification. The image sources are coming from Bing search results using an API so more times than not it works but every now and then it returns a 301 response. I honestly would need to run the script a while before it returns a 301...

Comment: Have you considered rerunning the GET request against the `Location` header value in the response? That should tell you where the image has moved.

Comment: @mdickin I have not. I guess that would be more efficient than retrying the `async.waterfall`? I am fairly new to JavaScript so unsure of what that would look like. Any examples would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I imagine it would look like. I added calls to the callback, as async would need that to continue.

Note that you could possibly get in a redirect loop, and I'm not sure if `.headers` is the correct property on the response.

```
function getImage(url, callback) {

    var http=require('http'), imageBuffer;

    http.get(
      url,
      function(res) {
        var body=new Buffer(0);

        if (res.statusCode!==200) {
            if (res.statusCode === 301) {
                getImage(res.headers["Location"], callback) //I'm  not sure if .headers is correct
                return;
            }
            console.error('HTTP '+res.statusCode);
            callback(new Error('HTTP '+res.statusCode)) //Might want a better error
        }

        res.on('data', function(chunk) {
          body=Buffer.concat([body, chunk]);
        });

        res.on('end', function() {
          imageBuffer=body;
          callback(null, imageBuffer)
        });

        res.on('error', function(err) {
          console.error(err);
          callback(err);
        });
      }
    );
}
```

Comment: I have been running the script without the `postTweet` portion of the `async.waterfall` and the majority of the time the `getImage` is successful. However, in addition to 301 response, there are at times, 403, and 400 responses as well. This script runs on a set interval function: `setInterval(function() {
  try {
    run();
  }
  catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}, 20000);` And it just performs another GET request if there is not a 200 response. I wonder if I should implement this logic instead of trying to account for the different responses?

Comment: If you're getting 4xx errors then I'd say the proper response would be to log the error and fail out. Calling the callback with an error would stop the waterfall, which would stop from tweeting. Then setInterval runs again later.

Comment: I just discovered this in the async documentation: https://github.com/caolan/async#retry

Comment: Looks like there is also a `retryable` option as well. https://github.com/caolan/async#retryableopts--times-5-interval-0-5-task